# Angular and Firebase: display error message to user

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, firebase

So I am pretty new to Angular JS, html, and css. When the user clicks the submit button it should either route to the landing page or return back to the login page and display and error message like "password and email combo provided are not recognized". Will I have to make calls to firebase to get the user's password and compare it to whatever they put in the password field in the form on submit?

I did something similar for registration but it was all in the html comparing the password and confirmation password to see if they matched, but I assume my request cannot all be in login-component.html.

login.component.html

```
<div class="form centerForm">
<h1>Login</h1>
<form [formGroup]="login" (ngSubmit)="onLogin(login)">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="user" formControlName="user" value='parent'>Parent
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="user" formControlName="user" value='child'>Child
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email: </label>
        <input placeholder="john.doe@email.com"
               formControlName="email"
               required>
        <br>
        <label>Password: </label>
        <input type="password"
               placeholder="password"
               formControlName="password"
               required>
        <br>

    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private router: Router,
              private authService: AuthService) {
  }

  login = new FormGroup({
    user: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    email : new FormControl('',
        [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    password : new FormControl('',
        [Validators.required])
  });


  get email() {
    return this.login.get('email');
  }

  get user() {
    return this.login.get('user');
  }

  get password() {
    return this.login.get('password');
  }


  onLogin(form) {
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;
    const user= form.value.user;
    this.authService.login(email, password, user);
    }



  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ChildService } from './child.service';
import { ParentService } from './parent.service';
import { PointsService } from './points.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  token;



  user= 'child';
  uid;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private childService: ChildService,
              private parentService: ParentService,
              private pointsService: PointsService) {
  }

  signUpParent(email: string, password: string){
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(
      response => {
        firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(
          (token: string) => {
              this.token = token;
                this.uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
                this.user='parent';
                console.log(this.uid)
          }).then( 
            response =>{
              this.parentService.addParent(email, this.uid);
              this.router.navigate(['home']);
            })
          .catch(
          error => {
            console.log(error);
            alert(error)
          });
        });
      }

      signUpChild(email: string, password: string, parentID:string, name: string){
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(
          response => {
            firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(
              (token: string) => {
                  this.token = token;
                    this.uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
                    this.user='child';
                    console.log(this.uid)
              }).then( 
                response =>{
                  this.childService.addChild(parentID, name, this.uid);
                  this.pointsService.addtoPointsDB(this.uid); 
                  this.router.navigate(['child-chores']);
                })
              .catch(
              error => {console.log(error);
              })
            });
          }

  login(email: string, password: string, user: string) {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(
            response => {
                firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(
                    (token: string) => {
                        this.token = token;
                        this.uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
                        this.user= user;
                        if(user=='parent'){
                          this.parentService.setParentID(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);}
                        else {
                          this.childService.setChildID(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                        }
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                      if(this.user=='child'){
                        this.router.navigate(['child-chores']);
                      }
                      else{
                        this.router.navigate(['home']);}
                      }).catch(
                    error => {console.log(error);
                    });
            });
}

logout() {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => console.log('logged you out')).catch(
        error => console.log(error)
    );
    this.token = null;
    this.childService.setChildNameIDPoints(null,null, null, null);
    this.router.navigate(['']);
}

isAuthenticated() {
  return this.token != null;
}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this might help:

auth.service;

```
    async loginByEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string, user: string) {
        await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user) => {
              firebase.auth().updateCurrentUser(firebase.auth().currentUser);

            if (user === 'parent') {
                 this.parentService.setParentID(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
            }
            else {
                 this.childService.setChildID(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            }
     });
}
```

logincomponent;

```
  async loginByEmailAndPassword(values) {
      this.accountErrorMessage = "";

      await this.authService.loginByEmailAndPassword(email, password)
         .then(() => {
            if (this.user == 'child') {
                this.router.navigate(['child-chores']);
            }
            else {
                this.router.navigate(['home']);
            }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          switch (error.code) {
            case "auth/invalid-email":
            case "auth/wrong-password":
            case "auth/user-not-found":
            {
               this.accountErrorMessage = "Wrong email address or password.";
               break;
            }
               default:
            {
                this.accountErrorMessage = "Unexpected Error";
                break;
            }
       }
  });
```

and add this to html to show the error;

```
<div *ngIf="accountErrorMessage">{{ accountErrorMessage }}</div>
```

And also, maybe you would like to use newest AngularFire plugin which I think makes using firebase functions easier sometimes. Especially router guards.

Comment: where did you get the "af" in afAuth?

Comment: ah sorry, I forgot to change that part. I am using angularFire plugin so I imported it as afAuth. I will edit the answer for "* as firebase"

Answer (score 0):

You need to call Firebase Authentication's `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` API with the email+password that the user entered.

If that fails, you then tell them to try again

Comment: where would I be making that call? in my onLogin function in the ts?